# Facebook Authentication/Account Linking for Dialog Flow (API.ai)

Tags: dialogflow-es, facebook-authentication

Google Actions SDK provides a way for Account Linking from the Google Developer Console wherein we can configure the redirect url for Account Linking. From here, I am redirecting to my custom url and upon successful authentication, the url returns an oAuth code.

[image]

I want to achieve the same for Facebook Account linking wherein for linking a user, it would redirect to my custom url and return the oAuth code for further processing.

Is there such capability for Account Linking FB and DialogFlow chatbot?

Comment: Hey I'm doing the same kind of thing, did you get any solution for account linking for facebook bot? Please tell me